# Javascript to validate required field entry on a VF page not working

Tags: java, javascript, visualforce, apex, force.com

I am trying to add some javascript for my visualforce page that is also a force.com site.

I have tried several different ways to get a field is required message to pop but it does not work. I pasted the code below, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<apex:form >

<script>
function doValidation(){
      var checkvalu = <apex:outputText value="{!customer}"/>;
      if(checkValu.length >0){
         saveNow();
      }
      else{
        alert('Please fill out all fields!');
     }
}
</script>
        <apex:panelGrid styleClass="section">Please enter your contact information</apex:panelGrid>

        <apex:panelGrid styleClass="survey">Name</apex:panelGrid>

        <apex:inputText styleClass="textarea" value="{!customer}"/>


        <apex:panelGrid styleClass="survey">Company</apex:panelGrid>

        <apex:inputText styleClass="textarea" value="{!company}"/>


        <apex:panelGrid styleClass="survey">Address</apex:panelGrid>

        <apex:inputText styleClass="textarea" value="{!Address}"/>


        <apex:panelGrid styleClass="survey">City/Town</apex:panelGrid>

        <apex:inputText styleClass="textarea" value="{!city}"/>


        <apex:panelGrid styleClass="survey">State/Province</apex:panelGrid>

        <apex:inputText styleClass="textarea" value="{!state}"/>


        <apex:panelGrid styleClass="survey">Zip/Postal Code</apex:panelGrid>

        <apex:inputText styleClass="textarea" value="{!zip}"/>


        <apex:panelGrid styleClass="survey">Country</apex:panelGrid>

        <apex:inputText styleClass="textarea" value="{!country}"/>


        <apex:panelGrid styleClass="survey">Email Address</apex:panelGrid>

        <apex:inputText styleClass="textarea" value="{!email}"/>


        <apex:panelGrid styleClass="survey">Phone Number</apex:panelGrid>

        <apex:inputText styleClass="textarea" value="{!phone}"/>
```

Comment: Why you are putting Visualforce markup inside javascript code?

Comment: I'm trying to get the message to popup on a force.com site when someone is filling out the survey and they do not add a value to a required field. Is there a better way to add a popup message?

Comment: `var checkvalu = '{!customer}';` This should populate the `checkvalu` field if you are binding the `customer` variable correctly with the controller. Check for any script error with FireBug or similar tool.

Comment: @highfive that binding only works on page load, so it is not going to validate the form field; the checkvalu var popualtion is wrong anyways, the answer from @naveen is in the correct direction.

@BobPo Where do you call the `doValidation()` method? the code snippet seems incomplete

Answer (score 0):

You can directly make a field as required in Visualforce using required attribute to a specific component

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}" required="true"/>
```

To make a field required using Javascript in VisualForce page please

```
<apex:page StandardController="Account">
    <script>
        function setRequired() {
            if (document
                    .getElementById('{!$Component.theForm.thePageBlock.thePageBlockSection.accPhone}').value == '')
                alert("Phone number will not be blank");

        }
    </script>
    <apex:form id="theForm">
        <apex:pageBlock id="thePageBlock">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton value="submit" action="{!save}"
                    onclick="setRequired();" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="thePageBlockSection">
                <apex:inputField id="accPhone" value="{!Account.Phone}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Regards,
Naveen
Software Engineer
http://www.autorabit.com